# How to access third party Android app within my app if they are not providing API?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app which needs to call other third party Android app and they are not providing any API/REST calls to get info like getting price of particular product/service etc.

Is it possible to get info of what third party app is selling if they are not providing APIs? I am new to Android.

Comment: Please explain what "call other third party Android app" means. Please explain what "get info about third party app".

Comment: What makes you think that you have the rights to that data?

Comment: I strongly encourage you to retain a qualified attorney, plus start building up your legal defense fund.

Comment: Not feasible. It is only possible if third-party app exposes required data to through content provider, but again it's not possible to install that 3'rd party app along with your app and make them write custom content provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If an application developer has not created a public API for you to use, then third-party applications cannot use that app to get data.

If you want support for getting information from a specific application, you should contact the developer of that application to explore your options.